# Reading configs into dictionary with a guaranteed order

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a few configs inside my Appsettings.json that I would like to read into a dictionary which is fairly easy with new framework. 
This is what my code looks like:

Options File:

`public Dictionary<string, string> Mappings { get; set; }`

Configs:

```
Mappings: {
  "a":"b",
  "c":"d",
}
```

Now I can bind this particular section inside the startup.cs and it's done.

Due to some requirements I have to change the above dictionary to something like this:

`public Dictionary<string, IList<string>> Mappings { get; set; }`

and new Configs looks like this:

```
Mappings: {
  "a":["b1","b2],
  "c":["d"],
}
```

I can read them into dictionary like before but I would like to know if the order of the list is guaranteed to be the one I specified or it can be random. So in above case, for Ilist of key == a, will b1 be always before b2?

I tried on my local and it works, but is this something which asp.net core guarantee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend entirely on what `IList<T>` implementation you choose.  If you use a `List<T>`, the items will be in the order added (unless you insert them into a specific position).  But an arbitrary `IList<T>` internally can do whatever it wants to do to the order of the items, as long as it implements the methods provided.

Comment: Hey, noticed you haven't posted in a while. Just wanted to check on you - make sure everything's okay. You've always had great things to say, both here and on Meta. I'm sure the community is missing your input.

Comment: @mason I appreciate the sentiment.  The company, and the moderation staff, has been working tirelessly for a long time to make this a place that's not enjoyable to participate in anymore for people interested in the site's founding mission and principles.  As of late they've succeeded in removing my remaining motivation for participating.